# How do I install a bidet spray on my toilets?

Tags: plumbing

I have decided that I have flushed enough trees down my toilets and wish to install a bidet spray. I am looking at something like https://amz.run/3RTh

The setup seems to be working with toilets connected through a flexible hose to the water line. The T branching is put on one end of such hose. Unfortunately, my toilets are connected with an elbow pipe, non bendable of course, see attached picture. Is it still possible to install the spray? Do you think I need to replace the elbow with a hose first?

[image]

Comment: i think that you are on the wrong track ... you seem to have forgotten about the desired temperature of the spray

Comment: The water coming out of this line is cold I guess. I am fine with washing my backside with it. Anything not burning hot is good here.

Comment: @Kris Toilet paper is not environmental friendly, it's all I meant. See https://achnews.org/2019/05/20/humans-wipe-out-about-270000-trees-a-day-with-toilet-paper/ We are literally cutting down forests to - inefficiently - clean ourselves. And I am not here for advice on my diet FYI.

Comment: Don't forget, nearly every single tree being cut down today for lumber and/or paper use has been planted _explicitly_ to be harvested for this purpose. While those trees are growing, they provide lots of habitat for wildlife and convert a lot of CO2 into O2 for us to breathe.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the water off and remove that elbow. Install a new flex line so you can add the T and you will be in business. You may not want to but I would add a valve so just in case if the new flex line or bidet line decide to spray at other areas than your back side you will be able to turn it off quickly. The bidet has a shutoff valve after looking again so it may not be that important to have a valve I just like local shutoff valves for when things go wrong.

Comment: I think that "elbow" is a valve.

Comment: If that elbow is a valve it would be missing a handle

Comment: And such handle, if it was there, would be facing to the floor in the worst ever position to ever try to use it in an emergency.

Comment: Meaning that I need to shutoff the water in the bathroom+toilets before doing the works right? About adding a new flex line, I am not sure how to pick the correct one, with the right entrypoints. I am in the UK, is it standardized? II might just remove the elbow and take it to a DIY shop.

Comment: Yes turn the water off you may want to place a pan to catch any drips and if the home is multi story a pot to catch any water that drains out of the pipe. On this side of the pond they are standardized I would take the elbow with you to make sure the sizes are correct. Jason may be correct on that elbow being a valve , but with it in that location you don’t have much room to work.

Comment: I would do exactly what Ed suggested.  Although I find it challenging due to the location of your pipe. There isn't much room to squeeze things in there.